# Google Scholar hits-per-page url string

Tags: url

I'm querying Google Scholar and pulling the first X number of results. In default mode, searches return 10 hits per page. This can be changed via a browser by editing the settings.

Does anyone know if there is a parameter I can pass along with the search query that will edit this without requiring a preference change?

For the record, Google Scholar does not provide an API, which is why I'm using url strings.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the query param you are looking for is **num**. Default value for it is 10.

Another param that might be of an interest is **start**, which is responsible for the pagination, it actually tells Google what result should be first on the page you see.

An interesting fact is that if you combine *num* and *start* in any way, it will still work. E.g. http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=10&num=25&q=capetown&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 will get you 25 results starting with 11th and this will be considered the second page of the search results.

[image]

Comment: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?num=100&q=stackoverflow does not result in 100 items. This query param seems to be broken now.

Comment: apparently they don't let you select the amount of results anymore.

Comment: Seems to be limited to 20 i.e. num=x works for x<=20, but if x>20 then it just returns 20.

Comment: `pagesize=100` seems to do the trick on scholar.google.com/citations?